# npm intstall: binding.node is missing

Tags: npm, node-sass

I tried to install npm on my local machine (Mac OS) but when I run npm start, it keeps giving me this error with node_sass. Even when I run 
    sudo npm install node_sass 
it doesn't fix the problem.

```
Error: You probably need to execute `npm install` to install brunch plugins.                               
Error: `/Users/AnhLe/bloc/anh-jams/node_modules/sass-brunch/node_modules/node-sass/bin/darwin-x64-v8-3.28/binding.node` is missing. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?


npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! bloc-rdio-skeleton@0.0.1 start: `brunch watch --server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bloc-rdio-skeleton@0.0.1 start script 'brunch watch --server'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bloc-rdio-skeleton package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     brunch watch --server
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bloc-rdio-skeleton
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/AnhLe/bloc/anh-jams/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Are you running Windows, Linux, or Mac OS?  Please add a tag for your operating system.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I run on Mac OS

Answer (score 0):

Looked around and these people are experiencing a similar error due to binding.node missing from SASS.

https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/185